# For loop that checks if table exists, then creates it if not before continuing with script

Tags: python, postgresql, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that checks if my postgres table exists already and if it DOES NOT exist, creates it before continuing with the rest of the script.  And if it DOES exist, doesn't bother creating it, but instead continues the script (which writes a file to the DB).

Somewhere, something in my for loop is incorrect.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
"""A tool for saving files to and from a postgresql db.
"""
import os
import sys
import argparse
import psycopg2

db_conn_str = "postgresql://word:word@111.11.111.1:5432/DBNAME"
create_table_stm = """
CREATE TABLE files (
    id serial primary key,
    orig_filename text not null,
    file_data bytea not null
)
"""

check_for_table = """
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM files)
"""

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser_action = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    parser_action.add_argument("--store", action='store_const', const=True, help="Load an image from the named file and save it in the DB")
    parser_action.add_argument("--fetch", type=int, help="Fetch an image from the DB and store it in the named file, overwriting it if it exists. Takes the database file identifier as an argument.", metavar='42')
    parser.add_argument("filename", help="Name of file to write to / fetch from")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

    conn = psycopg2.connect(db_conn_str)
    curs = conn.cursor()

    # Check if the table already exists
    if curs.execute(check_for_table) is None:

    # If it DOES NOT exist, create it
        curs.execute(create_table_stm)

    # If it DOES exist, ??
    elif     
        if args.store:
            with open(args.filename,'rb') as f:
                filedata = psycopg2.Binary(f.read())
                curs.execute("INSERT INTO files(id, orig_filename, file_data) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s,%s) RETURNING id", (args.filename, filedata))
                print curs
                returned_id = curs.fetchone()[0]
            print("Stored {0} into DB record {1}".format(args.filename, returned_id))
            conn.commit()

        elif args.fetch is not None:
            with open(args.filename,'wb') as f:
                curs.execute("SELECT file_data, orig_filename FROM files WHERE id = %s", (int(args.fetch),))
                (file_data, orig_filename) = curs.fetchone()
                f.write(file_data)
            print("Fetched {0} into file {1}; original filename was {2}".format(args.fetch, args.filename, orig_filename))

        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files`??

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS??" That works from PostgreSQL 9.1+  @roganjosh

Comment: Checking and creating the table if it does not exists is overkill because it will be running two queries. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Ah, eliminating the for-loop altogether!!  Amazing.  Thank you.

Comment: @RaymondNijland so from 2011. Am I missing the point you're making?

Comment: Even if there _were_ a reason to do this, why do you want a `for` loop to do something that happens either 0 times or 1 time? That's what an `if` statement is for. You even wrote your pseudocode comment as `if it DOES NOT exist, create it`, not `for each <something> do <something>`.

Comment: "so from 2011. Am I missing the point you're making?" telling that that query only works from PostgreSQL 9.1+ that was mine point.. Nothing more nothing less @roganjosh .. Some might be using a older PostgreSQL server version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `create table if not exists` and continue along.

```
create_table_stm = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
    id serial primary key,
    orig_filename text not null,
    file_data bytea not null
)
"""
```

There is a caveat, a table with the same name but different schema (ie. different columns and types) might already exist. Postgres will not verify that it matches your create statement, only that the table name matches.

If all you need is to create a fresh, blank table with a specific schema use `drop table if exists files` and then `create table files`.

Comment: "There is a caveat, a table with the same name but different schema might already exist."  Then use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.files (` instead.

Comment: @RaymondNijland "different schema" meaning different columns and types, not the fully qualified table name.